# ViewPager within a CoordinatorLayout (for sticky header purposes) leads to broken scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-viewpager2

Test app demonstrating the problem here: https://github.com/jstubing/ViewPagerTest

I'm using a CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout combo to achieve a sticky header within a scrollable page. At the very bottom of the page is a ViewPager2. When I swipe to a new `ViewPager` page, content loads asynchronously and populates a `RecyclerView` within the ViewPager. This all works well.

The problem occurs when I swipe to a new `ViewPager` page. At this point, the content loads and renders fine but I am no longer able to initiate a scroll outside of the ViewPager. In other words, swiping up and down in the "UPPER PAGE CONTENT" section (see XML) does nothing.

However, scrolling up and down does work within the ViewPager. If I scroll up or down in the ViewPager, or even just tap the ViewPager once, it fixes everything and I am again able to initiate a scroll from outside of the `ViewPager`.

I tried switching to the original `ViewPager` instead of ViewPager2 and it has definitely been more reliable, but the problem still happens every so often.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Ultimately I just want to be able to swipe between `ViewPager` pages and have the whole entire activity remain scrollable. I'm so confused as to why I lose scrolling ability in the first place, and why tapping on the `ViewPager` fixes it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                <!-- UPPER PAGE CONTENT -->

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <!-- Sticky header -->
            <include
                android:id="@+id/sticky_header"
                layout="@layout/sticky_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/events_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have a `RecyclerView`  in the `ViewPager` page fragment?

Comment: Yes, the ViewPager page fragment is a ConstraintLayout with a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem occurs when I swipe to a new ViewPager page. At this
> point, the content loads and renders fine but I am no longer able to
> initiate a scroll outside of the ViewPager.
>
> I am again able to initiate a scroll from outside of the ViewPager.

So, the problem is now limited to the `ViewPager`. Most probably because the `ViewPager2` supports nested scrolling through its inner `RecyclerView` (I don't mean the `RecyclerView` of the page, but the one that makes the `ViewPager` functions internally.

So, first thing we need to disable this nested-scrolling of the `ViewPager2`:

Kotlin:

```
viewPager.children.find { it is RecyclerView }?.let {
        (it as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
}
```

Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < viewPager.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = viewPager.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof RecyclerView) 
        child.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}
```

We can't completely disable the nested scrolling because this will badly affect the scrolling outside, so, we can manipulate this by a `NestedScrollView` that wraps the `ViewPager`:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/events_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: When I surround it in a NestedScrollView I no longer see the ViewPager. I posted a test app which demonstrates my originally posted problem here: https://github.com/jstubing/ViewPagerTest

If you open that test app and swipe over to the next page in the ViewPager, you'll notice that you can no longer scroll up and down outside of the ViewPager. But once you tap the ViewPager, it works again.

Comment: @SilentByte Thanks for sharing that.. Just add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `NestedScrollView` .. It works with me now